# MUNIT4 :java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.mule.extension.http.api.HttpRequestAttributes

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, munit

Imtrying munit set-event processor;

```
<munit:behavior >
            <munit:set-event doc:name="Set Event" doc:id="3ffb4e58-3938-4316-9533-f0031ad492a6" >
                <munit:payload value='{ .. }' encoding="UTF-8" mediaType="application/json" />
                <munit:attributes value="#[{headers:{'application-id':'test'},method:'POST'}]" />

            </munit:set-event>
```

It reads my payload and attributes coreectly. I put a log and checked. 
But after that I get;

```
ERROR 2020-05-21 15:46:23,622 [[MuleRuntime].cpuLight.05: [xxxx-api-v1].raml-main.CPU_LITE @41d3521e] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.mule.extension.http.api.HttpRequestAttributes.
Element               : raml-main/processors/4 @ xxxxxx-api-v1:api.xml:57
Element XML           : <apikit:router config-ref="raml-config"></apikit:router>
Error type            : MULE:UNKNOWN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.mule.extension.http.api.HttpRequestAttributes
    at org.mule.module.apikit.Router.processEvent(Router.java:133)
    at org.mule.module.apikit.Router.processWithExtension(Router.java:122)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.MessageProcessors.lambda$flatMap$13(MessageProcessors.java:338)
```

Why is that? what is wrong in my set-event processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the MUnit test is trying to mock the HTTP Listener, by setting the attributes of the HTTP request received in an expression. That expression translates into a Java Map. But APIKit expects the actual class that implements the HTTP Listener attributes. Mocking in this way will not work.

To implement it the right way, in Anypoint Studio right click on the APIKit router and click in the menu entry Create Test Suite for XXX.xml from API specification. That will create a skeleton for your tests.

Alternatively you can check this example in Anypoint Exchange: https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/org.mule.examples/testing-apikit-with-munit/

Comment: I  tried to generate from apikit router. But getting  "The MUnit Suite file to open could not be found". I tried updating and installed latest anypoint studio.(v 7.5.1). But same error occurs. I could not use  exchange, because we are using only runtime. And I use, only anypoint tsudio to develop flows.

Comment: These are the logs //
!ENTRY org.mule.tooling.core 4 0 2020-05-25 11:46:42.614
!MESSAGE Error while parsing API: null

!ENTRY org.mule.tooling.core 2 0 2020-05-25 11:46:42.616
!MESSAGE AMF parsing failed, fallback into RAML parser
//

Comment: It looks like the API RAML has some issue and the parser is complaining. Try to edit the RAML in Studio or in API Designer to see if it shows any errors or warnings.

Comment: I dont see any errors. I generated flow from my raml. (so, i think its right)..I used, anypoint studio raml editor..